# Creating a table with nested loops in python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm learning abort nested loops and I've gotten an assignment to create a function that takes two integer inputs. Then it should create something like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXXh.jpg). Only problem is that when I use an odd number for columns it doesnt work.

It has to be an "advanced nested loop" for the assignment to be approved.

```
def createTable(rows, columns):
    rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
    columns = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))

    for row in range(rows):
        if row%2 == 0:              
            for col in range(0, columns):
                if col%2 == 1:
                    if col != columns - 1:
                        print(" ", end="")
                    else:
                        print(" ")
                else:
                    print("|", end="")
        else:
            print("-" * (columns - 1))
            
    return True
```

createTable(1, 2)

Comment: You didn't ask a question

Comment: Can you show us your code? And what is exactly 、not working、?

Comment: Please provide the code that you're using which is leading to this problem. Additionally, how many columns do you want? Your image shows 20 columns while you entered 40.

Comment: @Psmacks **edit** your post, we can't read code in the comments.

Comment: Sorry....haven't quite learned the ways of doing things here yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made one iteration of the code which you want. It prints the correct output for even and odd number of rows and columns. It is very similar to the outputs you want. When you provide further clarification for your question, I can provide an updated code.

```
rows = 20
columns = 41

for i in range(rows):
    if i%2 == 0:
        output = "| " * (columns//2)
        print(output)
    else: 
        output = "-" * ((columns//2)*2 - 1)
        print(output)
```

The output can be visualised below. Hope this solves your query.

[image]

Based on the code provided by the question provider, I have edited the code and the following code will work in the same manner as you want it to with nested loops.

```
def createtable(rows, columns): 
    for row in range(rows):
        if row%2 == 0:              
            for col in range(0, ((columns+1)//2)*2, 2):
                print("| ", end="")
            print()
        else:
            print("-" * (((columns+1)//2)*2 - 1))

    return True
```

Tested for both these cases.

```py
createTable(20, 40)
createTable(20, 41)
createTable(2, 1)
```

Comment: I see it does what I need, but the assignment says it has to be an "advanced nested loop". But thanks alot for taking your time to help.

Comment: This is a more efficient way of doing it actually. You can convert the lines inside if and else to loops as well. Please put the question. As such, there is no such thing as 'advanced nested loop' in python. Please provide questions with more clarity otherwise people might downvote it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and heads up...I will try to in the future.

Comment: @Psmacks I have added a solution for the case of the nested loop as well using the function definition you provided.

Comment: Great thanks! I've will go through the code and try understand the logics in it.